# Single transaction for multiple steps (scheduled job t-sql)

Tags: t-sql, transactions

I wonder if it is possible to cover all the steps of a job with a single transaction. Like,

```
TRY (BEGIN TRAN; STEP1 ) CATCH(ROLLBACK)
TRY (STEP2) CATCH(ROLLBACK)
TRY (STEP3-last step) CATCH(ROLLBACK)COMMIT;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of; steps are atomic units of work in a job.  If you need to cover them all in a transaction, you should move all of the activities into a single step.